# how to set background image in relative layout programmatically in on create?

Tags: java, android-relativelayout, setbackground

I used the code layout.setbackgroundresource(R.drawable.image) in on create method to set background image of layout. But when i try to run on device it stopped working without opening the screen. Please help in this problem.

this is the code which i wrote in oncreate method
mainlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.darkbackground);

**MainActivity:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaKy1.png)

**error logcat:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u1jT.png)

it crashes my app when opening the app.

Comment: pls check your logcat and share error message with us. so we can _help_.

Comment: Is this in your main activity? Did you call `setContentView(R.layout.idOfYourLayout)` ? For example: `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` If so, please share relevant code and your layout xml.

Comment: A print screen of the error might be useful.

Comment: i have added some screenshots of the problem. Can you check now.

Comment: problem seems to be in your line 87 something to do with your service unable to start. please check

Answer (score -1):

The issue is not with the Image view. Its because of the Google Api i.e Firebase Analytics.

Try disable the Firebase analytics in your code and run the app. If it's working, then fix the Firebase issue.